# Nesting Tables in SQL Server Express

Tags: sql, sql-server-express

I am creating a purchase order system where someone can store details of their purchase. So I created a database, with tables for supplier information from which we will buy stuff and another table where we store what we are buying.

In the `PurchaseOrder` table, there are columns for :

- PurchaseOrderNo (Primary)
- BuyerInitials
- DateOfPurchase
- ProjectCode
- Items (linking to the PurchaseItems table)

I want to add another column with Items' details, so I created another table `PurchaseItems` which has the following columns:

- PurchaseOrderNo. (this would be repeat for each part)
- PartNo
- Description
- Quantity
- UnitAmount
- VATAmount
- TotalAmount

Logically it seems simple, but I can't seem to get my head around on how I would link the tables. Thank you very much for the help :)

Comment: LInk them with `Foreign Key` constraints on PurchaseOrderNo column.

Answer (score 0):

Create a seperate table say OrderedItems which maps the PartNo and PurchaseOrderNo. This avoids the repetition of PurchaseOrderNo in each row and also maintains the relation between PurchaseOrder and PurchaseItems table.